# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, cmd, command-prompt, fatal-error, mysql-connector

[image: Fatal error in launcher]

when I am trying to install "Mysqlclient Package" in my python by applying this command getting this error in the command prompt

C:\Users\prash\Downloads>pip install mysqlclient-2.0.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"d:\python\python.exe"  "D:\python\Scripts\pip.exe" install mysqlclient-2.0.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl': The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: have you tried just a regular ```pip install <PackageName>```

Comment: yes I tried everything but earlier it didn't work but now I fixed it thankyou